# Run (Gem) executable in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I want create a Gem with an executable or something else which helps. I am open for ideas.
This executable should modify specific Models in my Rails app. But it needs access to the complete Model and the underlying table (columns, datatypes ...)

For example, I want call the executable like this:

*execute [some action] [name of model]*

**In action**: *execute show Post*

In the Rails Console I could access the hole Model, like "Model.column_names", but could not run excutables from a Gem. On the normal command line I have no access to the Rails Model and the underlying things ...

How could I realize my idea of a custom command line tool which could access Rails Models?

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like a [rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org) task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor) gem is definitely what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That helps me a lot. Now, I will try [custom rake tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) and / or write [custom generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).